# Create default QGIS actions / define my own default actions

Tags: qgis, actions

I have created a simple action that should be used to several users. Then, I'd like to put my action among their default action list.

Put it simply, how can I create a default qgis action in a given QGIS instance? Or how can I set my function as default, so that when I restart QGIS I can find it there again.

Comment: I found a nice solution. I save to the database the style of the layer in which I created the action. Then, whenever the user import the layer it is there. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a nice solution. I save to the database the style of the layer in which I created the action. Then, whenever the user import the layer it is there. ;)